# Pass argument to the controller via uses Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I am doing some routing with Laravel. I need to pass url part as argument to the controller.

I know this is possible with: `Route::get('user/{name}', function($name){});` but since all my code until now is routed in this way: `Route::get('/{param}', array('uses' => 'CustomerController@index')`

I want to be consistent and therefore wondering if it is possible to pass argument in this way to the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Simply declare your `CustomerController::index` method like this:

```
public function index($param)
{
}
```

Reference: http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#basic-controllers

Note that a default value is required for optional parameters. For example,

```
// the route
Route::get("/{param?}", array("uses"=>"CustomerController@index"));

// in the controller
public function index($param = null)
{
}
```

Without the default value, you will get "missing parameter" errors when Laravel tries to route to the method with no parameter.

Comment: so laravel is so smart it figures out that function needs param and it passes to it? probably reflection power?

Comment: It reads the route configuration, which spells out the parameters it needs to extract from the URL, then passes whatever value(s) it finds to the method via [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php).

Answer (score 1):

I see you just accepted an answer, but I'll hit submit for an alternate version...

You can inject a custom service, lets call it UrlProvider, into the constructor of the controller. Then, just access the service to get the relevant parts of the URL. Please forgive any syntax errors, it has been some years since I've written any PHP...

```
public class MyController
{

  private $urlP;

  //dont forget to bind the UrlProvider in the IoC setup.
  public __construct(UrlProvider provider)
  {
    $urlP = provider
  }

  public function Index()
  {
    urlP.GetUrl();
  }

}

public class UrlProvider()
{

  function getUrl()
  {
    //you can parse out the relevant part of the URL here if you need.
    return Request::path();
  }

}
```

Comment: I don't think using $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] is a good idea, since Laravel takes care of that through Request object.